# Only JQuery working with FormData?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am sending form contents via an AJAX call.

The form is:

```
<form id="id_of_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
  <br/><br/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

My preferred method is the following:

**Method 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_of_form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);      

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "testing.php", true);

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                var returnVal = ajax.responseText;

                ... do stuff here ...
            }
        }
        ajax.send(formdata);
    });
});

</script>
```

This *sorta works*. In my PHP, `if($_POST)` returns *TRUE*, but `if($_FILES)` returns *FALSE* (when both the name and file field contain something). When I do `var_dump($_POST)` in my PHP, it spits out the following:

```
array(312) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryoypwTdV9MSCqJC2F Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(5698) ""name" qwert ------WebKitFormBoundaryoypwTdV9MSCqJC2F Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileField"; filename="carved-coral-beads.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg ���� VExifMM* ���=�19(1A2_��s������i ��SA
```

^ Only an abbreviation - actually MUCH longer.

`var_dump($_FILES)` returns

```
array(0) { }
```

*Method 1* only works when I send data in the following way:

```
ajax.send("username=something&var2=somethingelse");
```

but I can't include any files (specifically, an image) in this way.

If I use JQuery to send it:

**Method 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_of_form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "testing.php", 
            type: "POST",    
            data: formdata, 
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,      
            processData:false, 
            success: function(data){
                ... do stuff here ...
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

it works just fine, and I can parse the contents and file in my PHP.

Just out of habit, I would like to use the *Method 1*. Why will *Method 2* with the JQuery version work just fine, but the first method flops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it'll work just fine also, the one line you pointed out doesn't work since you have a variable typo on Method #1:

```
var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
ajax.send(formData); // formdata != formData
```

Sidenote: I can't setup a demo yet, http://codepad.viper-7.com I think is still down (at least on my end). I'll set it up later once I can access but here's what I would have used.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
}

?>

<form id="id_of_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
  <br/><br/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_of_form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var name_value = document.getElementById('name').value;
        formdata.append('name', name_value);  // append value

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", document.URL, true);


        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                var returnVal = ajax.responseText;
                console.log(returnVal);
            }
        }
        ajax.send(formdata);
    });
});
</script>
```

Important Note: Handle `$_FILES` for your uploaded file and handle `$_POST` for your text inputs.

Comment: Fixing the typo sends the data (text field, file field). But in my PHP, I get `if($_POST)` returns *TRUE* while `if($_FILES)` returns *FALSE*. Should they not both return true? And I cannot access `$_POST['name']`, but I can using the JQuery method. `var_dump($_POST)` gives the following... `array(312) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryoypwTdV9MSCqJC2F Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(5698) ""name" qwert ------WebKitFormBoundaryoypwTdV9MSCqJC2F Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileField"; filename="carved-coral-beads.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg ���� VExifMM*` and on...

Comment: @Birrel why would you use `$_POST` to handle file uploads? its in `$_FILES`

Comment: I have a text field to ("name"). The line `echo $_POST['name']` returns nothing. That's why I did the var dump for `$_POST` - to check what was there. Obviously not a simple key/value pair, but some jumbled mess. I've edited the original question to include your typo fix, and explain what I'm getting.

Comment: @Birrel of course you're getting nothing on the `$_POST` since you haven't appended your input values, use the script i setup, this is for a single page demo for this sake

Comment: Using your code, `echo $_POST['name'];` still returns nothing. And what about appending the file? I know *how* to do it, but it does not work. If you look at the var_dump in the original question, and read through it, you'll see that both the name field and file field are being sent to the PHP, just in some unreadable format. Every search I've looked for requires the JQuery to be set up with `contentType: false` and `processData:false`. Doing so in the JQuery AJAX call allows the JQuery to automatically determine the type for each. Is this where I'm falling short?

Comment: The data is being sent, I just can't use it.

Comment: @Birrel its funny, this is the time i need to setup a online demo and the site isn't working lol. this is working on my side but anyways. you're checking the `console.log`'s dump on the console browser tab right?

Comment: I'm checking the dump by assigning the inner HTML of a div on the page. It's easier and quicker when running it. `$_POST['name']` is undefined in all browsers.

Comment: @Birrel since i can't prove its working fine on my end, (because of the blasted down demo site), i'll just ping you later when its working and setup a demo. here's the console.log's return on my end in the console browser `Array
(
    [fileField] => Array
        (
            [name] => 51GgnQRwlaL.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php558B.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 35492
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => test
)`

Comment: Copied and pasted your solution exactly (rather than transcribing), and it works just fine. Comparing the back and forth they are identical. Not sure what's up. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Birrel yes, thats how i've set it up, just the same page, including the PHP, it'll just be on that same file. of course that wouldn't be the case if the PHP is seperated elsewhere, you'll just need to change `document.URL` to where you PHP resides